# Battery status not showing

Tags: battery

How do I keep the battery status on as to see how much life is left in my battery? I configured this to be on all the time in the power management but it only shows the amount left when I am charging the battery. When I am unplugged, I don't get the battery status. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Battery status applet in ubuntu,using the following commands in your terminal,

- Adding repository

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iaz/battery-status && sudo apt-get update`
  `sudo apt-get install battery-status`
- Updating repository

  `sudo apt-get update`
- Installing Battery status

  `sudo apt-get install battery-status`
- After installation right click on your panel **→** Select **Add to Panel**  **→** And then add **Battery Applet**

Answer (score 0):

I tried that as well, same thing, it can't get the program.... however, putting in 
`watch -n 1 acpi -b` 
in Terminal works like a charm, but only when the battery monitor is on, and to do THAT the power cord needs to either be in, or, in for a second or two, and taken out, its odd.