# Check Bluetooth headphones battery status in Linux

Tags: bluetooth, battery, headphones

Is it possible to get the battery status of Bluetooth headphones connected to Linux? Android shows it so I was wondering if it was possible.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55008142/2907484

Comment: Quite an old answer, not sure still works or not! https://askubuntu.com/questions/20698/battery-status-not-showing

Answer (score 70):

I am not sure about the state under Ubuntu, but under Arch Linux you do not need to write your own scripts to get bluetooth battery information nowadays.

The bluez package has experimental support for querying bluetooth headset battery data. Simply enable experimental features by editing

```
/etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

and adding the following line to the `[General]` section

```
Experimental = true
```

Then, you just need to restart the bluetooth service using

```
systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Reconnect to your device, and

```
bluetoothctl info
```

should now also show the battery status. e.g.

```
Device 28:11:A5:47:6C:6E (public)                                             
Name: Cloud Walker                                                    
Alias: Cloud Walker                                                   
Class: 0x00240418                                                            
Icon: audio-headphones                                                
Paired: yes                                                           
...                               
Battery Percentage: 0x3c (60)
```

The solution using upower as given by danjjl should also work now.

And now the battery level percentage should show up in Gnome Power settings dialog as well.

Before:
[image: Before bluez Experimental option enabled, Cloud Walker bluetooth headset is not displayed in Devices section of Power settings]

After:
[image: After bluez Experimental option enabled, Cloud Walker bluetooth headset is displayed in Devices section of Power settings]

Comment: Thanks, just got this working on Arch thanks to your answer! It also gets it showing in the Power settings UI for Gnome too! Ubuntu must have enabled the Experimental bit in their upstream of `bluez`. I just added some UI screenshots as well as example output from `bluetoothctl info`. Oddly though, `bluetoothctl info` only shows one device, e.g. not my MX Master mouse battery as well. I'm looking forward to these battery levels showing natively in the system tray settings dropdown too!

Comment: Thanks. Works on Ubuntu as well

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS with 5.15.0-58-generic kernel.

Comment: I was working to build a script and shows at status bar, but with this 50 % of work was skipped

Comment: It works under Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: This approach of enabling experimental features works great. However, this specific method of editing the `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` does not work for me, at all. The method that does work is editing the `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service` to add `--experimental` flag, as can be seen in [the docs](https://bluez-cheat-sheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Cheers!

Comment: Did not work for me, but it might be because of Pipewire. Alirezas Python script also doesn't.

Comment: works just perfect under openSUSE tumbleweed, thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Working on 23.10.
(thanks!)

Comment: @AneesAhmed777 Make sure to put the `Experimental=true` config in the `[General]` section of `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`. The end of the file might not be the correct section.

Comment: worked perfectly on Fedora 37, both bluetoothctl and gnome 43.9

Answer (score 24):

I wrote a simple python script that does the job. It uses AT commands to communicate with the device via RFCOMM and prints the battery level if the device is supported.

https://github.com/TheWeirdDev/Bluetooth_Headset_Battery_Level

(You need Python 3.6.0 or newer to run the script)

It might not work with all bluetooth headsets but I've provided a couple of workarounds in the 'Issues' page that might help.

Comment: Thank you for doing the job for the community

Comment: Thank you! Do you have print screens, just want to see how its looks like.

Comment: @Qui-GonJinn it's a command line tool. It simply prints the battery level, for example something like this:   Battery level for XX:YY:ZZ:AA:BB:CC is 80%

Comment: Using port `.2` I get `<MAC adress> is offline (16, 'Device or resource busy')`.
Using other ports I get `<MAC adress> is offline (111, 'Connection refused')`.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Worth adding that "bluetoothctl devices" shows the required MAC addresses

Comment: @AlirezaS.N It gives me `bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy` exception. (Trying to get battery status from Apple AirPods).

Answer (score 24):

In ubuntu you can go simply to `settings->power` to see the battery status of system and connected devices.

[image]

Yes, I know it's a Microsoft Bluetooth mouse on a Linux System ... but hey, Microsoft is the new cool company now ;)

This is what: `systemctl status bluetooth`

[image]

This is what: `bluetoothctl` devices shows:

[image]

The JBL was disconnected and the Creative speaker is connected with power. So the resulting ones with batteries (Keychron and Mouse) show up in the `settings->power` dialog.

NOTE:
If `upower -d` not show the device, It's power level may not display in settings .
// I had a mouse shown, but a headphone not.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see the first section "Devices" on my machine. I've the same Ubuntu20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: @Rajesh Chaudhary Can you run a `upower -d` and see what the output is ?

Comment: Here you go @klaas https://pastebin.com/zskLJmtr

Comment: Hmm, seems you don't have any connected devices. Probably a last check if BT stack is running. You can check it with `systemctl status bluetooth` Which should state *loaded* and *active*. If that is the case you can use `bluetoothctl` which open an _internal_ cli. Enter `devices`which should give a list of the connected devices. I add the outputs for my system in the answer above.

Comment: I don't think so. I was connected to Bluetooth device & still connected now. Please see this once. https://imgur.com/a/HYgvg06

Comment: Seems to be dependent on the device. I found the issue and comment from the maintainer below in the gnome.org gitlab issues [Source,see here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/224): Quote: "..
    **the device needs to show up in the output of upower -d to show up in the Power Settings panel (whether that's a laptop or a desktop). Right now, this means only devices which export their battery status in the kernel, and Bluetooth LE devices which export the battery via the BATT profile are supported.**.."

Answer (score 13):

`upower` can be used from a terminal to list power devices, listening to device events and querying history and statistics.

If your device is listed by `upower -e` you can run `upower --dump` to retrieve the battery level of your device.

Here is a sample output:

```
$ upower --dump
...
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/mouse_dev_C1_FC_26_13_A9_58
  native-path:          /org/bluez/hci0/dev_C1_FC_26_13_A9_58
  model:                MX Anywhere 2S
  serial:               C1:FC:26:13:A9:58
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Wed 31 Dec 1969 06:00:00 PM CST (1550719462 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       no
  mouse
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        no
    state:               unknown
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          50%
    icon-name:          'battery-missing-symbolic'
...
```

[src reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/asc1st/how_to_check_the_battery_level_of_a_bluetooth/)

Comment: It did not show the bluetooth device, just the ac adapter, laptop battery and displaydevice.

Comment: @gabs1bb3 It shows.

Comment: @ÉdersonT.Szlachta not always. My phone can show the battery status of my device but Ubuntu (18.04) can't.

Comment: @gabs1bb3 Need to restart bluetooth daemon and reconnect the bluetooth device before upower method.

Answer (score 3):

I have developed a GUI application to get the battery level of a bluetooth headset. You can check it on: https://github.com/Coutj/Bluetooth_project.git

Answer (score 1):

For Airpods devices download and run https://github.com/delphiki/AirStatus with:

```
git clone git@github.com:delphiki/AirStatus.git
cd AirStatus
pip3 install bleak
python3 main.py
```