# How to get the battery info of a bluetooth device?

Tags: bash, kubuntu, bluetooth, battery, info

I've searched a lot and didn't find the proper solution for the problem I'm facing. I wonder if is there a way to see the battery level of a headset connected via bluetooth. I've checked the output of `bluetoothctl` already and it shows me the following information:

```
[EDIFIER W800BT]# info
Device 04:FE:A1:E9:70:DE (public)
        Name: EDIFIER W800BT
        Alias: EDIFIER W800BT
        Class: 0x00240404
        Icon: audio-card
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: yes
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
[EDIFIER W800BT]# show
Controller 74:40:BB:FE:F3:7C (public)
        Name: kennet
        Alias: kennet
        Class: 0x001c010c
        Powered: yes
        Discoverable: yes
        Pairable: yes
        UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
        UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0530
        Discovering: no
```

Additionally,

```
➜  ~ hcitool dev
Devices:
        hci0    74:40:BB:FE:F3:7C
```

Also, I found nothing on:

```
➜  ~ ls -l /sys/class/bluetooth/hci0/power/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 dez 27 19:11 async
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 dez 27 19:11 autosuspend_delay_ms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 dez 27 19:11 control
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 dez 27 19:11 runtime_active_kids
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 dez 27 19:11 runtime_active_time
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 dez 27 19:11 runtime_enabled
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 dez 27 19:11 runtime_status
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 dez 27 19:11 runtime_suspended_time
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 dez 27 19:11 runtime_usage
```

Comment: Why are you thinking the device reports it?

Comment: @Pilot6 Because it reports when I connect to my android device. Am I wrong to think it would report connecting to my computer?

Comment: Well, then it really does. I just asked ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check Bluetooth headphones battery status in Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117563/check-bluetooth-headphones-battery-status-in-linux)

Comment: I've tried the upower --dump also, and it doesn't report the battery there. And I'm trying to make the python script works to report back.

Comment: @Pilot6 The script doesn't work also. I've also tried the 30 ports suggested in the README.md of the github project. :/

Comment: I've found that I need to disconnect from my computer before check the battery, but the script turns off my bluetooth headset when I execute it.

Answer (score 1):

Using this extension following the install guide worked for me.
https://github.com/MichalW/gnome-bluetooth-battery-indicator

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1218220)