# How can I check the battery level of my Bluetooth mouse?

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10.  Is there a way to check the battery level of my Bluetooth mouse--or must I just charge it and hope? This is a very generic mouse with no identifying information and an on-off switch --nothing more. (It works fine.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078659 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117563 - One of those questions might have an answer that works for you. Also, what mouse do you have? I realize this doesn't directly answer what you asked, but some have battery indicators built-in, typically in the form of an LED or light of some kind