# Unable to see battery status of Bluetooth devices under Power Settings in 22.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, power-management, battery

Even though I am currently playing music through a Bluetooth speaker using Rhythmbox, in Power settings, I am unable to see its battery status. Some other topics had screenshots which say it is possible to check the battery status of connected devices through Settings > Power.

It would be nice to know how to see make them available under Settings > Power. Or any other reliable means available.

I am using 22.04. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please give the info where I can see these screenshots of seeing the power of attached devices.

Comment: Answer 2 of this question :  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117563/check-bluetooth-headphones-battery-status-in-linux